# How to hide "Customer matched zone ****" notifications on WooCommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

When woocommerce debug mode is turned on, on the cart page and checkout page, there appears a notification says "Customer matched zone ***".

Is there any way that makes woocommerce not show this message with debug mode enabled?

Answer (score 1):

As per my knowledge, you can not do this by using any WooCommerce action/filter but you may do this by using jQuery as shown below:

```
jQuery( ".woocommerce-message" ).each(function( index ) {
    let checkText = jQuery(this).text();
    if (checkText.indexOf("Customer matched zone") != -1) {
        jQuery(this).css("display", "none");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can set "woocommerce_shipping_debug_mode" option value to "no".